# How to fix " Error using pde.PDEModel/geometryFromEdges" in matlab

Tags: matlab, pde

I have problem in executing PDE function in Matlab. When try to run

```
geometryFromEdges(model,g);
```

there's an error:

```
Error using pde.PDEModel/geometryFromEdges (line 46)
Assemblies of more than one geometric model are not currently supported.
```

I'm using Matlab R21016a.

So how to fix this problem? thanks!